# Get the value of an id

Tags: javascript

I have images:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test(this)"><img id="j" src="../images/pix_green.jpg" border="0" /></a>
```

And onclick I want to get back the value of id for each images. So there is my function:

```
function test(obj)
{
    var img = obj.childNodes[0];
    alert(img.value);
    if (event.wheelDelta >= 120)
        unit -= 60;
    else
        unit += 60;
    request(readData);
}
```

The problem is that `alert(img.id)` print `"j"` and not the value of `j`.

How could I get the value of `j` ?

my JSOn is like this after parse:

```
1413815100=true
1413815160=true
1413815220=true
1413815280=true
1413815880=false
1413815940=false
1413816000=false
etc..
```

And `j` when I print it is the value 1413.. but impossible to put it as an id

This is how I parse my json and put my img :

```
function parse_data(data)
{
 var json = data;
 var obj = JSON.parse(json);
 var buff = "";
 for(var i in obj)
 {
  document.write('<br>' + i + '<br>');
  for (var j in obj[i])
    {
      document.write(j + "=" + obj[i][j] + '<br>');
      if (obj[i][j] == true)
        buff += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"test(this)\" ><img  id=\"j\" src=\"../images/pix_green.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
      else
        buff += "<a href=\"#\" onmousewheel=\"test(this)\" ><img src=\"../images/pix_gray.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
      //document.write(j);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     }
    buff += "<br>";
   }
  document.getElementById('frisekk').innerHTML = buff;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect the value of `j` to be? there's no `value` attribute

Comment: the value of `j` clearly is `Andy`

Comment: it should be like 1405648 the value that my json parse

Comment: @leykan that is something we would find useful to know.. can we see your json and how you're storing it

Comment: "it should be like 1405648" -> W... w... whaaaaaat??

Comment: @AJPerez nop its doesn't work value is undifined

Comment: @leykan - i fear for the resolution of your problem, you need to provide us with some real data we can use, "its like this" isnt going to help.. is it `var myJSON = {"1413815100":true,"141381560":true};` if so, how is `j` supposed to relate to any of this?

Comment: As a side note: id's cannot start numeric, CSS will not apply

Comment: Ok but if I do j.toString it will print me j.toString why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are not accessing `j` as a variable, it's just being written as a piece of the string.

You need to break the string and reconnect it.. replace

```
buff += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"test(this)\" ><img  id=\"j\" src=\"../images/pix_green.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
```

with

```
buff += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"test(this)\" ><img  id=\"" + j + "\" src=\"../images/pix_green.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
```

or change it to

```
buff += '<a href="#" onclick="test(this)" ><img  id="' + j + '" src="../images/pix_green.jpg" border="0" /></a>';
```

Comment: @leykan no worries - easier to sort these things when you supply as much detail as possible.. in this case, it was the function that showed us the issue, glad it help